# How to: Excel Ribbon with multiple Workbook-level ribbon items with dynamic attributes?

Tags: xml, vba, add-in, excel-2007, ribbon

I am trying to work out a solution to share most of my VBA codebase across workbooks. This involves creating a `.xlam` file that would contain the shared modules & classes (+ their respective factories).

I'm willing to use Office 2007's wonderful RibbonUI, and have that `.xlam` file declare a custom tab (Let us call it `MyTab` for the sake of the argument). I need `MyTab` to only display some elements if the user has specific permissions (which I manage through VBA).

Besides that, I want my other workbooks to be able to add stuff into `MyTab`, which may also have dynamic elements (that use VBA).

The issue I'm facing is that whenever I get in the case where a workbook references the `AddIn.xlam` and declares dynamic ribbon elements, Excel tries to refresh all at once, thus calling VBA code in two separate threads (I guess), which eventually fails (because VBA is single-thread-forced in Excel), and generates blank dialog boxes with just "400" written on those and two buttons "OK" and "Help".

Has someone got experience on how to best tackle this issue?

Comment: Acquire a lock? From my experience, you do not want to do any serious development in Excel. It bytes you in ways that do not make any sense.

Comment: I know Excel's bad... But I don't have an option (trying to deprecate all that stuff, but resource constraints make it that I can't do it in few weeks...), so I'm just trying to make it less painful.

How could I acquire a lock knowing that VBA shouldn't allow me to run two separate functions at a time anyway (which is causing the issue here).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried setting `Application.MultiThreadedCalculation = False`.

I believe that will correct your issue.

Comment: I'll try this when I come back from holiday :)

Comment: That partially fixed it. But it drove other issues. I guess the core design of VBA breaks my use case... I'm going to use other ways now... :)